# Inserting Special character at specific length in a string

Tags: c#, string

I want to insert `-` in between them at `4` digits interval in the given string. In the string there will be no special characters and it is a controller code.

```
string char = "123456789012"
```

I want answer

```
string char = "1234-5678-9012"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) (combined with [`String.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the trailing dash):

```
string str = "123456789012";
string res = Regex.Replace(str, @"\d{4}", match => match + "-").Trim('-');

Console.WriteLine(res); // 1234-5678-9012
```

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem. Thanks.  Can you explain why are you using match => match + "-". I can't understand that.

Comment: That means the match for the Regex pattern `\d{4}` - 4 consecutive digits, check the given msdn reference for details.

Answer (score 0):

As a *non*-regex alternative, you can use [`Batch`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) from [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)  like;

```
string s = "123456789012";
var list = s.Batch(4, seq => new string(seq.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", list));
```

Prints

```
1234-5678-9012
```